# Story where a (child?) protagonist gradually explores lower decks of generation ship?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, generation-ship

I can't remember the name or author of this generation ship short story, where the (child?) protagonist descends to progressively lower decks and encounters the various unfathomable technologies that make "normal life" possible.

IIRC:

- The protagonist was a male child, and was at some point scolded over or warned against his wandering too far below.
- He (?) found various manuals or other printed materials (related to the technical operations of the ship) written in a language/alphabet he didn't recognize.
- I think there was a discovery of the grisly remains of the engineering staff (I'm less sure of this).

Note that this wasn't a novel or serial; just a short story, *maybe* 10 pages if printed, though I believe I read it online for free.

I know these themes are hardly unique, so perhaps a tough/ambiguous ask. Sorry ᖍ(ツ)ᖌ, and thanks!

Comment: @user14111 I've thought of a couple of additional bits (which I'll edit into the question in a second), but I'm afraid I don't have a lot of other details.

Comment: Possibly one of the novellas that later became [Orphans of the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphans_of_the_Sky)?  See [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v27n03_1941-05?q=Hugh+Hoyland).

Comment: Was there a part where the protagonist finds himself in a water tank or an area flooded with water? I want to say that I've read the same thing...

Comment: There is a similar story I am familiar with, but it's has mutants, and a anti change religion that despises change. I am interested in the answer.